# how can i disable default menu in gojs

Tags: menu, gojs

i'm new to `gojs`,
when i **press** my mobile's screen (`#myDiagram div`) in page , some default menu shows up but i don't want it.

i try to disable it by setting `"toolManager.isEnable":false`, but didn't work

```js
 myDiagram =
        $(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv",
          {
            initialAutoScale: go.Diagram.Uniform,
            initialContentAlignment: go.Spot.Center,
            allowDrop: false,
            allowMove: false,
            "toolManager.isEnable":false,
            nodeSelectionAdornmentTemplate:
              $(go.Adornment, "Auto",
                { layerName: "Grid" }, 
                $(go.Placeholder)
              ),
            layout:  // use a custom layout, defined below
              $(GenogramLayout, { direction: 90, layerSpacing: 30, columnSpacing: 10 })
          });
```

how can i disable it?

here is what shows after press
[image: here is what shows after press]

Answer (score 0):

As described in https://gojs.net/latest/intro/contextmenus.html#DefaultContextMenuForTouchEnabledDevices, you can just set a **ContextMenuTool** property to null.  For example, during the initialization of a **Diagram**:

```
$(go.Diagram, . . .,
  {
    "contextMenuTool.defaultTouchContextMenu": null
  })
```